# Discrepancy between actual size of coordinates and clipped satellite image box sizes

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api, copernicus

I've marked an area of interest on a map (`aoi2`) and applied the `clip()` function to satellite images based on these coordinates.

However, there is a discrepancy between the actual size of the coordinates and the size of the box in the clipped satellite images.

I'm really curious about the reason for this. I am a university student studying in South Korea, and I have been looking for a solution for over half a day but can't find an answer, so I'm asking here.

```
import geemap, ee
ee.Initialize()
Map2 = geemap.Map()

aoi2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-80.12480511144283, 9.34580402882444],
      [-79.66126346730358, 9.34580402882444],
      [-79.66126346730358, 8.982192273390574],
      [-80.12480511144283, 8.982192273390574]]])

Map2.addLayer(aoi2)

startDate = '2018-07-01'
endDate = '2018-07-31'


sentinelImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') \
    .filterBounds(aoi2) \
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
print("Number of images = ", sentinelImageCollection.size())



sentinelImage = sentinelImageCollection \
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE') \
    .first() \
    .clip(aoi2)
print("Sentinel image taken at = ", sentinelImage.date())

Map2.addLayer(
    sentinelImage,
    {'min': 0.0, 'max': 2000, 'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']},
    'RGB'
)

# Calculate NDWI (Normalized Difference Water Index)
ndwi = sentinelImage.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']).rename('NDWI')

# Add NDWI layer to the map
Map2.addLayer(
    ndwi,
    {'palette': ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue']},
    'NDWI'
)
Map2.centerObject(aoi2,12)
Map2
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since you use `.first()` function, you get one image which you see after the code runs. To solve this issue:

(1) remove `.first()` method and filter the collection by `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE`.

```
sentinelImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') \
    .filterBounds(aoi2) \
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate) \
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 15)) \
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')
```

(2) use `.map` function to get normalized and clipped images.

```
ndwi = sentinelImageCollection.map(
        lambda image: image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']) \
            .clip(aoi2) \
            .rename('NDWI'))
```

Script:

```
import geemap, ee
ee.Initialize()

Map2 = geemap.Map()

aoi2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-80.12480511144283, 9.34580402882444],
      [-79.66126346730358, 9.34580402882444],
      [-79.66126346730358, 8.982192273390574],
      [-80.12480511144283, 8.982192273390574]]])

Map2.addLayer(aoi2)

startDate = '2018-07-01'
endDate = '2018-07-31'

sentinelImageCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2') \
    .filterBounds(aoi2) \
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate) \
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 15)) \
    .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')

Map2.addLayer(sentinelImageCollection, {'min': 0.0, 'max': 2000, 'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2']}, 'RGB')

# Calculate NDWI (Normalized Difference Water Index)
ndwi = sentinelImageCollection.map(
    lambda image: image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B8']) \
        .clip(aoi2) \
        .rename('NDWI'))

# Add NDWI layer to the map
Map2.addLayer(ndwi, {'palette': ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'blue']}, 'NDWI')

Map2.centerObject(aoi2, 11)
Map2
```

[image]

The result still has empty space because the images placed there have higher cloud value than 15 and I guess 1-month interval is not adequate because the images between '2018-07-01' and '2018-07-31' are too cloudy.

Comment: I'm really thankful. As someone majoring in public administration, I had a hard time studying these topics. Thanks to you, it's been a happy morning. I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is caused by the method `.first()`. Your AOI may consist of two images. you can remove this `.clip()` to confirm it.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your comments

Correct. As you mentioned, upon checking the .first() image, I found that this image strangely only covers a part of the designated aoi range. When I looked at the fifth image in the index, it closely (about 90 percent) fell within the specified aoi2 range. But I'm not sure if I need to keep checking by entering the index like this every time, or if there was an issue with the first filterBounds(aoi2).